# nSubstitute issue mocking httpContext and the session due to expected cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking, nsubstitute

I have an MVC app where I'm trying to mock my home controller such that my `controller.Index()` should be called.

The issue is on the constructor of my homeController. Here's the actual code:

```
 public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, IUserRepository<CompanyUser> userRepository, IAuthorisationChecks authorisationChecks) : base(httpContext, userRepository, authorisationChecks)
    {

    }
```

and my base class has the following:

```
public  ControllerBase(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext,IUserRepository<CompanyUser> userRepository,IAuthorisationChecks authorisationChecks)
    {
        _authorisationChecks = authorisationChecks;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _httpContext = httpContext;

        var cookie = _httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["auth"];
        var userCookie = _authorisationChecks.UnencryptedCookieValue("userdata", cookie);

       var userDeserialised = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SignInModel>(userCookie);
            userDeserialised.SessionId = _httpContext.HttpContext.Session.Id;
        var loggedInUser = Task.Run(async () => await _userRepository.SignInAsync(userDeserialised)).Result;
        _httpContext.HttpContext.Session.SetCurrentUser(loggedInUser);

    }
```

in My test I currently have:

```
[Fact]
    public void Index_Returns_Correct_View_Test()
    {
        // Arrange

        var httpRequest = Substitute.For<HttpRequest>();
        var session = Substitute.For<ISession>();
        var httpResponse = Substitute.For<HttpResponse>();
        var httpContext = Substitute.For<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var userRepository = Substitute.For<IUserRepository<EvaluateUser>>();
        var authorisationChecks = Substitute.For<IAuthorisationChecks>();

        userRepository.SignInAsync(new SignInModel
        {
            EmailAddress = _configuration["user:emailAddress"],
            Password = _configuration["user:password"],
            UserName = _configuration["user:username"],
            SessionId = _configuration["user:sessionId"]
        });

        session.Id.Returns(_configuration["user:sessionId"]);

        httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Returns(httpRequest);
        httpContext.HttpContext.Session.Returns(session);
        httpContext.HttpContext.Response.Returns(httpResponse);


        var controller = new HomeController(httpContext, userRepository, authorisationChecks);

        // Act
        var result = controller.Index();

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
    }
```

When I attempt to run the test, it fails on the line in controllerBase that tries to set `userDeserialised.SessionID` because `var cookie` is empty. How can I mock this into my test so that my test will pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to stub out the cookie content, then the `_authorisationChecks` call as well:

```
val authCookie = "my-cookie-content";
httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["auth"].Returns(authCookie);

val userCookie = "{ json serialised sign-in model here }";
_authorisationChecks.UnencryptedCookieValue("userdata", authCookie).Returns(userCookie);
```